# The number of lines that contains integers in a file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, integer

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
count1=0;
count2=0;
for n in $*
do
for(i=1;i<='wc -l <$n';i++) do
        if [[ $i == *"[0-9]* ]]; then

                count1=count1+1;
        else
                count2=count2+1;
        fi
        done
done
```

count1 is for lines that contains integers and count2 for lines that doesn't contain integers.

Input:

```
yes 145 10
no no
10 20
```

Output:

```
count1=2, count2=1
```

Comment: The quotes around `wc -l <$n` should be backticks.

Comment: You shouldn't have a double quote in `*"[0-9]*`

Comment: `count1=count1+1` is not the correct way to increment a variable in `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep -c` to count the number of lines that match a regexp. Use the `-v` option to count the lines that don't match.

```
count1=$(grep -c "[0-9]" "$@")
count2=$(grep -v -c "[0-9]" "$@")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in $*
```

To loop over the positional parameters, use `"$@"` (with quotes) instead of `$*`. The former actually works with arguments containing whitespace (see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters)).

```
for(i=1;i<='wc -l <$n';i++) do
```

This should be `for ((i=1;i <= $(wc -l < $n); i++)) ; do` ([manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs)). As it's now, it's a syntax error. Even so, it would still only loop over the numbers, not read anything. See [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) on how to read a file.

```
if [[ $i == *"[0-9]* ]]; then
```

That's otherwise okay, except for the lone quote there.

```
count1=count1+1;
```

This will assign the string `count1+1` to the variable `count1`. You probably wanted to use an [Arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) here: `count1=$((count1 + 1))`